# Will have to get used to / be used to

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

There is a sentence:

> 1. I am a father now and I will have to get used to being called 'father'
> 2. I am a father now and I will have to be used to being called 'father'

What's the correct alternative? 
Be used to works as an adjective, so seems like it's possible to choose the second option the same as the first one because I am not used to so **I have to finally get used to it.**

Not sure what to choose, very vague for me.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about the process of becoming accustomed to something new, "get used to" is the correct expression. Since he has become a father **now** that implies he feels strange when someone calls him "father". Therefore he has to "get used to being called father"

"be used to" describes the state of being already accustomed to something.

> I would like to be used to the taste of coffee.

This is talking about the state of already enjoying (or not hating) the taste of coffee.

> I would like to get used to the taste of coffee.

This sentence also works, but sounds like it is talking about the journey to liking the taste of coffee, as opposed to the final state.

---

In general "get used to" is almost always right

The one exception would be "being used to" (state) vs. "getting used to" (journey)